# embedded neo4j: iterate over all nodes of a huge graph

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-embedded

I would like to iterate over all nodes in a ~100Mio-graph. I know I can get the nodes with the cypher-query

```
    MATCH n RETURN n
```

but then I would have to use LIMIT and SKIP to work myself through the dataset and I think there are performance-issues with this approach.

Now my question is: How can I iterate over all nodes using an embedded neo4j database? The whole thing will be a background job (indexing nodes to elasticsearch).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks guys for mentioning GraphAware, just to throw another approach into the mix: The problem with getting all nodes with vanilla `GlobalGraphOperations` is that it all happens in a single transaction. On a graph with 100M nodes, this won't work.

For this reason, [GraphAware Framework](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework) has a number of [`BatchTransactionExecutor`](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework/tree/master/tx-executor#batch-transactional-operations)s that we're using in our modules for re-indexing / recover and such scenarios where you need to do something for each node / relationship or a subset of these.

Let me post an example of how you would use this - it's from GraphAware's Schema Enforcement Module (not open source, hence posting here):

```java
    final List<String> violations = new LinkedList<>();

    new IterableInputBatchTransactionExecutor<>(database, 1000, 
            new AllNodes(database, 1000),
            new UnitOfWork<Node>() {
                @Override
                public void execute(GraphDatabaseService database, Node input, int batchNumber, int stepNumber) {
                    for (Constraint<Node> constraint : nodeConstraints) {
                        if (!constraint.satisfiedBy(input)) {
                            violations.add(input + " violates " + constraint.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).execute();
```

Most of the input parameters should be self-explanatory. Note that [`AllNodes`](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework/blob/master/tx-executor/src/main/java/com/graphaware/tx/executor/input/AllNodes.java) is another framework class which fetches all nodes from the `database` in batches of 1000 (in this case) per transaction. We provide others (`AllNodesWithLabel`, `AllRelationships`), but you can easily implement your own.

Doing this in the background is then a matter of creating a separate thread, or if you wanna get more sophisticated, use the framework's timer-driven modules as William already pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mention you are using embedded Neo4j you might want to use the Java API as documented [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/) instead of Cypher.

Specifically the class `GlobalGraphOperations` provides a `getAllNodes()` method as documented [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/tooling/GlobalGraphOperations.html#getAllNodes()):

```
for (Node node : GlobalGraphOperations.at(db).getAllNodes()) {
  // Do something with the node here
}
```

**Edit**

A couple of other points to consider:

1. You could implement a [transaction hook handler](http://maxdemarzi.com/2015/03/25/triggers-in-neo4j/) to initiate the Elasticsearch indexing operation when the node is inserted/updated instead of iterating through all nodes in the database.
2. If you want this operation to run periodically in the background you might want to consider using [GraphAware framework's](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework) timer driven [runtime module](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework/tree/master/runtime). This plugin provides a runtime for executing operations periodically in the background, and can be configured to scale back as the database load increases.

Comment: Note also that GraphAware has already a module for ES replication : https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-to-elasticsearch

Comment: You can just batch the processing of the nodes you get back from getAllNodes() with several threads in a pool then it is really efficient.